# I can't submit my app to The Ubuntu App Showdown

Tags: application-development

please, give me some help:
1. The version of my Quickly is 0.4.3. Can I use this version or I must to renew it? How can I do this?
2. When I am using `dput` utility to submit it says that there are no sign in my `.changes` file. What should I do?
3. When I am using `quickly release` utility to submit it says that it can't find project. What should I do?
I'm glad that you would help me.

Comment: which version of ubuntu you are using ?

Comment: I am using the Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

1. You should use quickly 12.04 (`12.04-0ubuntu2` is the package version), which is available in Ubuntu 12.04.  If you are not running Ubuntu 12.04, you should either upgrade or run it in a virtual machine for your development environment.
2. You need to create a signed source package `(debuild -S`) in order to use dput to upload it to a PPA.  The GPG key used to sign the package should be attached to your Launchpad account.
3. You need to create a Launchpad project for your app then run `quickly configure lp-project [project name]` before you can use `quickly release`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to participate appshowdown contest you should use 12.04 
Ubuntu [app showdown rule](http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/rules/) says

> all entries must be submitted for the current stable release – Ubuntu
>   12.04

Comment: But can I use Ubuntu 10.04 LTS for development?

Comment: It is almost impossible , you should use 12.04 for developing apps for 12.04

Comment: But there is no clear mention of using Ubuntu 12.04 as developing platform. IMO it is logical choice to use the same platform for which, apps are to be developed.Must be version related or dependency problem.

Comment: Maybe I'll use virtual machine for this purpose.

Comment: How can I export PGP keys I used for registration on PPA and then import in VM?

Comment: You should post this as another question so it can be answered much quickly .